# Error 403 when posting comments to a custom post type from a different page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, comments, comment-form

Im trying to make a simple ticket support system by using custom post type, comments and a page.
So it works like this,

1. User creates a ticket with details and it's inserted into the custom post type "tickets" then the each input data given is inserted using post meta.
2. The postid is then with $_GET['view'] on the tickets page (wordpress default page) like this: mydomain.com/tickets/?view=123
3. When the $postid = $_GET['view'] isset & numeric, it uses the provided $postid in it on the custom query to access the ticket which was insert in the custom post type "tickets".
4. Inside the query while loop, the comment form is inserted like this: `<?php comment_form('',$postid);?>`

However, when sending i get this error:

> Sorry, comments are not allowed for this item.

And upon checking devtools, it saw this:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/123/wp-comments-post.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

I tried testing commenting the on page itself (not cross-posting) and it's working but if the comment is set for the given ticket/post id from the $_GET['view'] (i.e: 123)  it's NOT working.

I checked the post id and it's correct so it seems to be just a cross-posting issue. Is there any way around this?